# Invoke lot of methods on UI thread from bakcground threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

**Some information about my question:**

I have a Windows Forms application that has a multiple thread that paralelly computing for long time. While computing these threads modifying UI elements(eg. Labels, TextBoxes, Buttons, etc.) and writing to a RichTextBox.
I have a lot of delegate for thread safe calls and checking InvokeRequired a lot of times.
I have lot of methods like this:

```
private void AppendText(string text)
{
    if(richTextBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(myDelegate, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        richTextBox.Append(text);
    }
}
```

**My question is:**

Is it a good way of modifying controls on UI thread from background threads, or did I do some architectural mistakes?

Comment: Yes `Async-Await` is best and much cleaner way to do the same, while processing takes place in background, Ui is automatically updated on the Ui thread, no complex code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a simple code to explain the usage of `Async-Await`

```
public async Task Main()
{
    var result = await Background("Test");
    // Update Ui here, its on Ui thread
}

// Executed Asynchronously in the Background
public async Task<string> Background(string text)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(text);
}
```

- `Background` method is processed asynchronously, if its over network like db call, then no thread pool thread required, if its in-memory, it will use thread pool thread
- Once the `Background` method, result can be updated on the control, its automatically Ui thread
- You may even use `Task Parallel Library` explicitly to process data and then update result
- `await` is still a blocking call, though it will free up calling context, which means Ui will not freeze, it is still accessible, but its possible to have a non blocking call using `Task.Run`, which when returns can be used to update the Ui, though you always have to prevent Main / Ui thread from exiting

---

### Edit 1 (Async Button Click Event)

```
public async void Button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   await (Async Method Call)
   // Update Ui
}
```

---

Comment: I have a button click event, where I call my threads thats are working. How could I use async-await there?

Comment: All events can be async by default, follow the pattern I have used above, you need to just mark `async`, return a `void`, which shall be ideally used only for events and use `await` inside for making an asynchronous call

Comment: Check the **Edit 1 (Async Button Click Event)**